# Compressed file VS uncompressed file in mapreduce. which one gives better performence?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hdfs

I have a 10 GB csv file and i want to process it in Hadoop MapReduce. 
I have a 15 nodes(Datanode) cluster and i want to maximize the throughput.

What compression format should i use ? or Text file without compression will always give me better result over the compressed Text file. please explain the reason.

I used uncompressed file and it gave me better results over Snappy . Why is it so?

Comment: Depends on your data.  Some data can be compressed very well, others can barely be compressed at all.  I'd suggest you try a few and find what works best for your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Snappy compression is that it is not splittable, so Hadoop can't divide input file into chunks and run several mappers for input. So most likely your 10Gb file is processed by a single mapper (check it in application history UI). Since hadoop stores big files in separate blocks on different machines, some parts of this file are not even located on the mapper machine and have to be transferred over the network. That seems to be the main reason why Snappy compressed file works slower than plain text.

To avoid the problem you can use bzip2 compression or divide the file into chunks manually and compress each part with snappy.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. yes you are right thre is just one mapper running with snappy compression. So iss snappy compression not splitable with the textfile only or it can be splitted if avro/orc/sequence/parquet are used with snappy ?  and how about the other compression codecs like (LZO, gzip etc..) with text fileand container file formats(like Seq/avro/parquet/orc ). ?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I didnt work with avro or parquet, so can't tell about that. i know there are tricks to presplit LZO and gzip is unsplittable

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help anyways.